# Execute python script using email/outlook

Tags: python, outlook

I have a python script which connect with database,fire a query save a result in excel using pandas.

what I want is if somebody from ask for this excel,my script which is on server should get trigger and mail that excel to that user.

My idea is :
1 Set up a cronjob which will trigger the script every half an hour
2 once triggered script first read my emails
And if it finds some thing in my subject line /body it will continue and share the result
3 will share access key with user and if that key is present in email than only script will share the result

Now the  question is it feasible ?Some packages I can think of is O365 python package

Any suggestions??

Comment: Yes this is feasible. Check out [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) and [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/imaplib.html)

Comment: If you are in a corporate environment you will probably find that sending email via Exchange from any program other than Outlook is disabled by default. You can talk to your sysops about this, but I suspect they may be unsympathetic: they are generally *very* cagey about allowing access to the Exchange message store from 3rd-party programs like yours would be. Not even read access, let alone write access. So don't invest too much effort in doing this before you establish that it is allowed.